# Markdown header line problems

Tags: bug, design, markdown, markdown-rendering

So in markdown we have a header: `=`, `-`.

Like this:

### Hello

Hello

```
Hello
-
```

So there is no line! However, when editing a profile, in the preview box, there is a line.

However, when we view it in the profile itself, the lines do not show up. [image]

(As said by James, the dash and equal have a difference. However, it does not affect the profile page, only the preview box)
[image]

What happened to the line?

Comment: He he... how are you liking my script :)? :P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Of course

Answer (score 2):

Equals sign in markdown adds an underline.

I can confirm that when editing your profile, using `=` for a heading there is a line below the heading, but only within the preview.

I believe it's not rendering the line on the final output (ie save changes and view profile) because that area converts to HTML and doesn't use markdown. So it outputs the header with `<h1>` tags, which HTML header tags obviously don't add a "line".

If you want a line under a heading, or any section of your profile, then use a `<hr>` wherever you want the line.

Comment: No, [this](http://i.imgur.com/ps1MIbf.png) is a picture of the preview. And you can look at my profile so you won't need a screenshot. So its not the separator line.

Comment: @UniKitty See my edit - I *think* I've got there in the end. Seems to explain it. Let me know if I've still misunderstood.

Comment: Yeah, you got it. And I don't need lines, just wondering if its a bug. But web browsers don't use markdown to render, so the line is also HTML right? Therefore the profile should also be able to have the line.

Comment: @UniKitty The line created by an `=` heading should perhaps also render in the actual profile page, but for whatever reason it does not. Maybe it's by design, they didn't want underlined headings transferring to the profile, or possibly a bug and the script rendering (or saving) the line from the `=` heading is not converted to a `<hr>` for the HTML output. I can't explain that though, only speculate. Devs/Staff would know more.